# PHPList fails for email addresses with leading, trailing, or multiple adjacent dots

Tags: php, email, phplist

PHPList (version 2.10.17) fails to send messages to addresses that match one of the following formats:

```
my..Name@domain.com
myName.@domain.com
.myName@domain.com
```

the error message is `Could not instantiate mail function.`
The code in question is:

```
function MailSend($header, $body) {
    $to = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($this->to); $i++)
    {
        if($i != 0) { $to .= ", "; }
        $to .= $this->to[$i][0];
    }

    if ($this->Sender != "" && (bool) ini_get("safe_mode") === FALSE)
    {
        $old_from = ini_get("sendmail_from");
        ini_set("sendmail_from", $this->Sender);
        $params = sprintf("-oi -f %s", $this->Sender);
        $rt = @mail($to, $this->EncodeHeader($this->Subject), $body,
                    $header, $params);
    }
    else
        $rt = @mail($to, $this->EncodeHeader($this->Subject), $body, $header);

    if (isset($old_from))
        ini_set("sendmail_from", $old_from);

    if(!$rt)
    {
        $this->SetError($this->Lang("instantiate"));
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The chosen code path is:

```
   else
      $rt = @mail($to, $this->EncodeHeader($this->Subject), $body, $header);
```

I could not reproduce this error on my own webserver where I set up PHPList for testing purposes.
Unfortunately the only system that is showing this behaviour is the production system. To add to that, I don't have access to any logfiles on that system - so I don't really know what is wrong.
My best guess is, that some sort of "string escape" on `$to` is needed to make this work, but I am somewhat reluctant to tamper with a production system (other than inserting some logging output).

Does anyone know a workaround for this sort of problem?

Comment: You are repressing errors, why would you do that? Every time your code runs God kills a kitten. I hope you're proud of yourself.

Comment: @truth lol. You are right about repressing errors. Do not do that.

Comment: @Truth err... I'm not. Ask the guys from PHPList why they do it... I'm sure they've got plenty of reasons. The reason might be, that the script is executed through a cron job.

Comment: While it's not recommended, there are situations where suppressing and error is valid...

Comment: Would the person who downvoted please have the common courtesy to explain why he downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error, it is expected behavior. The local-part of an email address (the part before the `@`) may contain `.`, provided it is not the first nor the last character, and provided also that it does not appear two or more times consecutively. This means all three examples are invalid email addresses.

Read more about [valid email addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses).

Comment: interesting. Thanks a lot. However, I've been told that this worked before upgrading to the latest version. This problem was encountered (and worked around) in the previously installed version. Sadly, the information how they worked around this problem was lost.

Comment: If it worked before upgrading that would imply there was a bug in the system that allowed invalid email addresses to slip though.  If they slipped through, chances are close to 100% that it wouldn't make it to the intended destination anyway.

Comment: @colithium apparently, from tests on my Server they get through. It must be some configuration

Comment: @yas4891, do you mean that your server will try to send those emails, or that they actually get delivered? The latter seems rather unlikely. Even if your server accepts the email, it does not mean that it will get delivered. But if you don't receive or check the bounce reports, you'll never know.

Comment: I'm actually receiving those mails in the inbox of my account, but this might be because they are hosted by the same provider. I'm going to check if this works across provider-boundaries

Comment: Convinced client to downgrade to the "working" version and did some testing. Apparently the "working" version never tried to send to those addresses, hence no error being logged. After telling him about it, he agreed to delete the faulty addresses from database. Thanks for your help.